# is it possible to have to views side by side in a linearLayout orientation vertical

Tags: android

I would like for 2 views to be side by side like this:

Title: `EditText`

but the problem is that the `android:orientation="vertical"` in a `LinearLayout`, is there away which I can do that ?

here is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <EditTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/edittext" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for both views:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

And insert into Horizontal layout inserted in vertical layout

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">

<EditTextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I took back my green checkmark, because i realized that your orientation is: horizontal